# Designing database with entity relations

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

So I am new in designing databases and I'm trying to represent a db diagram for a system where students can rate professors and school. Also Students and Professors can have their account to login. 
Is this a proper presentation and am I missing anything as of entity relations ?
And I wasn't sure if i need to use any inheritance as well ..

[image: Entity Relation Diagram]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Enumerated columns are good indication for bad design.
   You need an additional table for values.
   Once that done, there is no need to separate school rating from professor rating  -
   use a general rating table containning the id of the rater (which is always a student in your case) and the id and type (school/professor) of the rated element.
2. I don't see any reason to put students and professors in different tables.
   Think of it as a person table with a role attribute.
   If a person can be both, than instead of the role attribute add 2 flags columns - is_student and is_professor.

Comment: Dudu i have tried implementing your points in my design but i kept failing.. is it possible you can help representing the new entity relation diagram ?

Comment: Let me give you the best advice you'll ever get for working with data. Create a small sample of data and play with it. Forget about everything else. When you're done, get back to the code/theory or whatever it is. talk to me after you've done this.

Answer (score 0):

It looks okay but are you sure the relatioship between SchoolRating and Student should be many to many? Wouldn't a rating just have one student (the student who did the rating)?

Also it's not clear to me why SchoolRating and ProfessorRating have so many value attributes.

Comment: I think you are right regarding the relation between schoolRating and Student.. Regarding many values thats because the rating will include couple extra questions that student will answer.. I was wondering if there is a need to add a course table since student will be rating the professor depending on course..

Answer (score 0):

Initial Review: Seems solid, may require another table or an expansion of SchoolRating.

When you are designing, focus on what your objects accomplish, the questions of facts they answer.

SchoolRating has values that represent the reviews or are they aggregates of a set amount of teachers? How are these reviews rectified with professor rating...or do they have no relation? (They clearly do in a school...so how does your design accomplish this?)

Why does a student have any direct relation with SchoolRating? Should not this table be a true FACT table for the values scored from the professors and/or some rating system?

Why can a student not have multiple teachers or multiple reviews? If a student fails a class but leaves a review...how does your structure rectify a new review from the same student?

Lastly, do not use the inheritance theory in your relational design. It is utterly incompatible with the relational set theory and the sooner you learn to purge that from your system, the better.

Think on terms of DIMENSIONS and FACTS. Think about cardinality, or how you plan to deal with slowly changing dimmensions, whether database columns will provide efficiency.

Concepts like Star-Schema, Snowflake design, of durable keys, natural keys probably should be consulted whenever you question your design.

At the end of the day, what questions your tables can answer and how the system will access these tables are as important, if not more, to the design methodology as it relates to normalization.